# Python: Concatenate items in a list

Tags: python

I have a homework assignment where we have to create a hangman game and I have most of it created. What I can't figure out is how to remove the brackets surrounding the list of characters that have been guessed.

```
  display(missed+correct, correct, secretword)
   print()
   print('So far you have guessed: ', sorted(totalstring))
   for letter in sorted(totalstring):
        pletter = letter + ','
   myguess = getGuess(missed+correct)
```

This is the code that I have for my list where I used a sorted function. I wanted the letters to be displayed like a, d, e instead of [a, d, e]

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for string.join() to concatenate the items in the list by a delimiter.

```
display(missed+correct, correct, secretword)
    print()
    print('So far you have guessed: ', ' '.join(sorted(totalstring)))
    for letter in sorted(totalstring):
        pletter = letter + ','
    myguess = getGuess(missed+correct)
```

Python docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! After I made the change, however my commas disappeared. How can I fix that?

Comment: You need `', '.join` instead of `' '.join`. I think that was just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to edit or comment, so posting the same code, but notice the ', ' used to call join:

```
display(missed+correct, correct, secretword)
    print()
    print('So far you have guessed: ', ', '.join(sorted(totalstring)))
    for letter in sorted(totalstring):
        pletter = letter + ','
    myguess = getGuess(missed+correct)
```